# Views - column display

Tags: drupal, view

Hello
I want to show nodes to the columns, depending on their term.
Is it possible via single view (term with depth arg)?

Answer (score 0):

It will be rather complicated to achieve this result using a single view. On the other hand, you could easily set up Panels and a view pane that gets some arguments from the pane's column container. There you could set the different terms you want to show in that column.